# Creating JSONObjects in android

Tags: java, android

I need to form a JSON object like this.

```
{
    "GroupID": 24536,
    "Section": [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

Here is what i have tried, but the section array is not getting properly formed when i look at my object structure.

```
JSONObject Object = new JSONObject();
Object.put("Group", GroupID);
int[] section = {1,2,3,4,5};
Object.put("Section", section);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    JSONObject Object = new JSONObject();
    Object.put("Group", GroupID);
    Integer[] section = {1,2,3,4,5};
    Object.put("Section", new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(section)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of `JSONArray` for inserting set of values that represent an array, in this case **int** array.

---

```
String strJson = null;
try{
    int[] section = {1,2,3,4,5};

    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("GroupId", 24536);
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    for(int i : section)
        ja.put(i);
    jo.put("Section", ja);

    strJson = jo.toString();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now you've got json string  inside `strJson`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
JSONObject Object = new JSONObject();
Object.put("Group", GroupID);
int[] section = {1,2,3,4,5};
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
arr.put(section);
Object.put("Section", arr);
```

Or create a Collection and set it as the value:

```
Collection c = Arrays.asList(section);
Object.put("Section", c);
```

Comment: Thanks branky.... why was not my case working... and why would an arraylist work?

Comment: Neither of them works, as its still going as "Section":["java.lang.int"]